# Modelling PostgreSQL Database Schema for Visitor Data with Custom Grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on designing a PostgreSQL database schema to efficiently store visitor data such as Country, City, Device Type, Day Parting, Custom Tokens, and other related information.

Currently, I can store these attributes individually and display them in separate tables. However, I want to create an optimized database model that allows for efficient querying and grouping of this data at custom levels.

For instance, I'd like to be able to query and group data similar to the example shown on this website: https://demo.binom.org/?page=Stats&camp_id=1&date=9&group1=4&group2=11&group3=1&val_page=All

Could you please provide guidance or best practices on how to design such a PostgreSQL database schema for this purpose? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Best Regards.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form